# Is there a way to have SQL Server automatically normalize duplicate strings?

Tags: sql-server

Given a simple structure

```
- Invoice
    - Id: int
    - CustomerId: int
- InvoiceLine
    - Id: int
    - InvoiceId: int
    - Description: nvarchar(50)
    - Price: decimal (18,4)
```

In this case, description describes the product. Following normalization rules, since this description will contain duplicates, a way of normalizaing it is to introduce a new `InvoiceLineDescription` table. This would eliminate duplicate data.

(*Side note: I'm fully aware the `InvoiceLine` maybe should get a `ProductId`, but that's besides the point I want to make*)

However, does SQL Server support a way of de-duping this data out of the box in an automatic fashion? In other words, given a columns with many duplicate strings; can SQL Server be configured to store these efficiently?

Comment: Why `Description` is in `InvoiceLine` and not `Products` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server won't modify the logical database design automatically for you, no.  However, you can use Columnstore indexes which internally have a dictionary that does de-dupe things to reduce on-disk storage space for highly repeated strings.  So, there is a physical database design solution to your problem.  Note that not all application types make sense to run natively on columnstores - a pure OLTP application would benefit from just putting the string into a different table (3NF) just fine using normal B-Tree indexes, and this is likely how you would want to attack a pure OLTP application.  If the table in question is rarely accessed, you could theoretically just vertically partition the table into two and then use columnstores on the one with strings, but you should test your application to make sure that the design choice makes sense before running in production.